# Creating a piecewise function that recurs indefinitely with a constant that needs to be solved each switch

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, equation-solving, piecewise

Okay, I know the title is a mouthful, but it is easier to express with functions.

I need these functions to repeat for t up to very large numbers (i.e. t = 36,000,000) and each function needs to be continuous. Because of that, each C needs to be recalculated at the end of each piece of the function. I know how to do the first 1200 seconds no problem, but making the function continue several times recalculating each C is what is stumping me.

for this problem,

```
Mn55(0) = 0
Mn56(0) = 0
p = 1E13
u = 1.10872E-05
lambda = 0.26659



if t%1200 = 1:

    Mn55(t) = -C1*e^(-ptu) + q/pu 
else:

    Mn55(t) = q*t + C2



if t%1200 = 1:

    Mn56(t) = C3*e^(-lambda*t) + phi*t*u*Mn55(t)/lambda - phi*u*Mn55(t)/lambda^2
else:
    
    Mn56(t) = C4*e^(lambda*t)



For further reference, these are the differential equations governing each variable.:




if t%1200 = 1:

    dMn55 = -u*phi*Mn55+Q   
else: 

    dMn55 = Q


if t%1200 = 1:

        dMn56/dt = u*phi*Mn55(t) - lambda*Mn56(t)
else:

        dMn56/dt = - lambda*Mn56(t)
```

A solution using either the differential equation or the solved analytical solutions are both valid. I just need to be able to create a plot of both equations Mn55(t) and Mn56(t).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the functions to be continuous at t=1200 and t=2400 (i.e. the endpoints of the condition `t % 1200 == 1`)? What do you mean by _"**repeat** for t up to very large numbers"_ and _"making the function continue several times"_? In the absence of any constraints, I don't think you can calculate the constants at all. It might be clearer if you include some plots of what you want your function to look like.

Comment: @pho The function *should* be continuous. I could hard code to solve each C, but I imagine there is a more elegant solution. What I mean by “repeat” is that the length of the function must be variable. It should be able to be run, from t=0 and to any time t.